# Convert Representation of datetime.date to Representation of pandas.Timestamp

Tags: python, regex, datetime, pandas

I've converted a bunch of code from using `datetime.date` objects to using `Timestamps`. The code is covered by a ton of unit tests, which means that I need to convert all the instances like `"datetime.date(2016, 12, 20)"` to `"Timestamp(2016-12-20)".
The easy solution is:

```
re.sub(r"datetime.date\((\d{4}), (\d{1,2}), (\d{1,2})\)", r"Timestamp(\1-\2-\3)", string)
```

Which works fine in some cases. The problem is that `date` uses one **or** two digits to display the month and day, whereas `Timestamp` always uses two. So if the date was `datetime.date(2016, 1, 1)` I'd get back `"Timestamp(2016-1-1)`" but the correct representation should be `"Timestamp(2016-01-01)"`.

Some of the string instances also contain multiple substring matches.

Is there a way that I can use `re.sub()` to do this conversion?

Comment: you should be able to `pd.to_datetime(datetime.date(2016, 12, 20))` or a list of them `pd.to_datetime([datetime.date(2016, 12, 20)])`

Comment: Except that these are already string representations of the objects. E.g. the string might be something like "{'Foo': datetime.date(2016, 1, 1), 'Bar': datetime.date(2016, 10, 19)}." I need to convert roughly 1000 substrings, without access to the actual objects.

Comment: `whereas Timestamp always uses two` - are you sure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string = "datetime.date(2016, 2, 20)"
def repl(matchobj):
    return "Timestamp(%s-%s-%s)"%(matchobj.group(1), matchobj.group(2).zfill(2), matchobj.group(3).zfill(2))

print re.sub(r"datetime.date\((\d{4}), (\d{1,2}), (\d{1,2})\)", repl, string)
```

Output:

`Timestamp(2016-02-20)`

Use `zfill` with width `2`.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a combination of `pd.to_datetime` and `eval`
make sure you import `datetime` to get eval to work.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

pd.to_datetime(eval("datetime.date(2016, 3, 31)"))

Timestamp('2016-03-31 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 1):

why can't you simply replace `datetime.date(` with `pd.Timestamp(`:

```
In [26]: datetime.date(2000,1,30)
Out[26]: datetime.date(2000, 1, 30)

In [27]: pd.Timestamp(2000,1,30)
Out[27]: Timestamp('2000-01-30 00:00:00')

In [28]: datetime.date(2000,1,3)
Out[28]: datetime.date(2000, 1, 3)

In [29]: pd.Timestamp(2000,1,3)
Out[29]: Timestamp('2000-01-03 00:00:00')
```

RegEx:

```
re.sub(r'datetime.date\s*\(', r'pd.Timestamp(', string)
```

pd.Timestamp **docstring**:

> **TimeStamp is the pandas equivalent of python's Datetime and is**
>   **interchangable with it in most cases**. It's the type used for the
>   entries that make up a DatetimeIndex, and other timeseries oriented
>   data structures in pandas.
>
> There are essentially three calling conventions for the constructor.
>   The primary form accepts four parameters. They can be passed by
>   position or keyword.
>
> Parameters
>   ---------- ts_input : datetime-like, str, int, float
>       Value to be converted to Timestamp freq : str, DateOffset
>       Offset which Timestamp will have tz : string, pytz.timezone, dateutil.tz.tzfile or None
>       Time zone for time which Timestamp will have. unit : string
>       numpy unit used for conversion, if ts_input is int or float offset : str, DateOffset
>       Deprecated, use freq
>
> The other two forms mimic the parameters from `datetime.datetime`.
>   They can be passed by either position or keyword, but not both mixed
>   together.
>
> ### :func:`datetime.datetime` Parameters
>
> .. versionadded:: 0.19.0
>
> year : int month : int day : int hour : int, optional, default is 0
>   minute : int, optional, default is 0 second : int, optional, default
>   is 0 microsecond : int, optional, default is 0 tzinfo :
>   datetime.tzinfo, optional, default is None